# Mozilla error SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Tags: firefox, ssl

I'm getting this error

> www.google.co.id
>
> uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because the
> issuer certificate is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate
> intermediate certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be
> imported.
>
> Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

this happend when using mozilla only, majority website undergo this error too, not all website tough

I has been trying delete cert8.db, adjust date, configure proxy, refresh mozilla from troubleshoot, clear cache, even reinstalling mozilla

[image: Ceterficate Viewer]

Comment: Your being sent an invalid certificate for that website

Comment: how do I resolve this?

Comment: Disable all MITM software features you have running on your pc

Comment: don't have MITM software

Comment: Something installed on your PC is causing a fake certificate to be sent to Firefox.  Some security software has a feature to scan HTTPS traffic.  Disable it.  You either have an add on, malware, or security software doing so

Comment: maybe so, but i has been uninstall last programs that i last install, even add-on all has been disable, currently doing full scan using avira

Comment: Avira is known to have this feature.

Comment: disabling avira and firewall doesn't make change, I even doesn't have avira web protection

Comment: Do you get that error on your personal or company computer? Depending on it it could also be issued by some proxy solution. With the information you provided it's likely that someone compromised your computer and/or connection. If you click on Details what Tree do you see?

Comment: it's my personal computer, and not using any proxy.
In detail top tree is www.google.com with each value of version, serial number, etc is nothing 
and yeah no proxy, or automaticly detect proxy doesn't work for me

Comment: [This is how the certificate is supposed to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwafx.png) You are very clearly subject to some interception.

Comment: cannot detect the interception, even avira especially web protection, and some mention mail protection has been uninstalled, problem still occurs

Answer (score 1):

I install malwarebyte and scan system. I think the problem lies in registry when scanned and repair. Restart and mozilla go back normally

Comment: To properly mark a question as answered, accept an answer. You'll probably have to wait a little until you can accept your own answer. Also, "I did stuff and it suddenly worked" is pretty much worthless for others that have the same/a similar problem.

Comment: @Daniel B On the contrary, while not being overly detailed, this is quite helpful. While "doing stuff and it working" is not a guarantee of causality (i.e. [post hoc ergo propter hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) is an informal logical fallacy), the answer isn't "pretty much worthless". It can be difficult to untangle causes of problems like this because of modern software's complexity. And once one solves such a problem, it can be difficult (and undesirable) to try to reproduce it. They should not be faulted for this answer; it's better than not coming back at all.